# Proving that $\lim_{n \to \infty}nx_n=\frac{1}{q}$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $0<x_1<1$, $x_{n+1}=x_n(1-x_n)$, prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} nx_n=1$.

Suppose now $0<x_1<\frac{1}{q}$ and  $0<q\leq 1$ and $x_{n+1}=x_n(1-qx_n)$, prove $\lim_{n \to \infty}nx_n=\frac{1}{q}$.

The first one can be done by showing the sequence is decreasing and bounded and therefore has a limit. What about the second one?

Comment: Substitute$$y_n = qx_n$$

Comment: How is showing that the sequence $x_n$ is bounded and decreasing sufficient to show $\lim_{n\to\infty} nx_n=1$??  You need a bit more work to verify the coveted limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We need first show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}n x_n=1$.

---

To begin, note that for $x\in (0,1)$, $0<x(1-x)<\frac14$.  Hence, provided $x_1\in(0,1)$, $x_n>0$.  Moreover, $x_{n+1}-x_n=-x_n^2<0$.

---

Inasmuch as $x_n$ is bounded below by $0$ and monotonically decreasing, the sequence converges.  Suppose it's limit is $L$.  Clearly $L=L(1-L)$.  Hence $L=0$ and we find $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=0$.

---

Let $a_n=1/x_n$.  Since $x_n\to 0$, then $a_n\to\infty$.

Hence, the Stolz-Cesaro Theorem guarantees that

$$ \begin{align}
 \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{nx_n} &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}n\\\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n)\\\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{1-x_n}\\\\
&=1
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown.

---

For the second part, let $y_n=qx_n$ as was already mentioned in a comment and another solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

It's essentialy the same as the first part, as :

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} nx_n = \frac{1}{q} \Leftrightarrow q \lim_{n \to \infty} nx_n = 1 \Leftrightarrow \lim_{n\to \infty} nqx_n = 1 $$

But isn't that $\lim_{n\to \infty} nz_n$ = 1 where $z_n \equiv qx_n$ ?

Answer (score 0):

We can show more than just the asymptotic behaviour

$$x_{n+1} = x_n(1-qx_n) \implies x_n = x_{n+1} + q x_{n}^2$$

divided by $x_{n+1}x_n$ results in

$$
\frac{1}{x_{n+1}} = \frac{1}{x_n} + q\underbrace{\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}}_{\ge 1}  \ge \frac{1}{x_n} + q
$$

Thus by the telescoping sum we have

$$
\frac{1}{x_{n}} - \frac{1}{x_1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{x_{k+1}} - \frac{1}{x_k} \ge (n-1)q
$$

which finally implies

$$
x_n \le \frac{1}{(n-1)q + \frac{1}{x_0}} \le \frac{1}{nq}
$$
where we have used $x_1\le 1/q$ for the last inequality (which we also need to ensure $x_{n+1}\le x_n$ by induction).